# Node.js read folder then files with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small challenge and my understanding with promises await and such things is not so good at moment, i can need some help to understand how to build my idea.

What i want to try is reading first a folder with files and then reading every files content after each other before doing the next step.

In my current code the problem is that the next then() block is execute before i want it to execute.

```js
let counter = 0;
//---
const getFolder = (foldername) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(foldername, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(files);
    });
  });
};
//---
getFolder('./filesarehere/')
  .then((folder) => {
    console.log('then 1');
    let amount = Object.size(folder);
    console.log('amount files ' + amount);
    let filenames = folder;

    filenames.forEach((file) => {
      let filePath2 = __dirname + '/filesarehere/' + file;
      fs.readFile(filePath2, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (data.length > 10) {
          counter++;
          console.log('counter ' + counter);
        }
      });
    });
    return counter;
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('then 2');
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Now the above code does print this in my console log:

```
then 1
amount files 14
then 2
0
counter 1
counter 2
counter 3
counter 4
counter 5
counter 6
counter 7
counter 8
counter 9
counter 10
counter 11
counter 12
counter 13
counter 14
```

the part where then 2 is print does get the counter value 0 because the files reading have not end and later when the file reading have start you see the counter of the files is print, but i want it to first read all files and then return the result to the next part of the code which is the next .then() code

I hope somebody can understand what i mean, i am not using much coders slang because i am not a expert just want to learn it all at moment.

Comment: This kind of work is far easier to code if you do it in an `async` function and `await` the results of directory and file operations. And, **pro tip**. Always format your code with indentation, as it's far easier to read and reason about. You'll thank yourself a year from now when you look at it again.

Comment: If you use async and await how would it look can you give a example? And why does my solution not work i did think promise is always good to use?

Comment: `async` and `await` ARE using promises, it's just an easier syntax to work with.

Comment: Also you aren't using promises here: `fs.readFile(filePath2, (err, data)`  - this is a callback.  You should use the promisified version instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `.then()` and `.catch()` on functions that return a `Promise`. Your `getFolder` function is doing it correctly, and the first `then()` that you are using is correct too. But the second `then()` is called on a function that is not returning a `Promise`.

I'm not sure how much you are familier with `Promises` and `async/await`, but I suggest reading about them before working with them, because they are part of asynchronous codes in javascript wich are kinda hard to work with if you don't understand them first.

Here I wrote a simplified version with `async/await`, hope it helps:

```js
// fs/promises has the same fs functions but the return a Promise
// instead of getting a callback
const fs = require('fs/promises');

// we can only use await in async functions, so we create a temporary
// async function
(async () => {
  let counter = 0;

  // await waits for a Promise to gets resolved
  // this returns both files and folders (directories)
  const files = await fs.readdir('./filesarehere');

  // Promise.all get an array of Promises
  await Promise.all(
    // each async function returns a Promise, so we map our files to a Promise
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = __dirname + '/filesarehere/' + file;

      // only use readFile if it's a file (not a folder)
      const isDir = (await fs.stat(filePath)).isDirectory();
      if (!isDir) {
        // here again we are waiting for the results of fs.readFile
        const data = await fs.readFile(filePath);
        if (data.length > 10) {
          counter++;
        }
        // the counter is passed into resolve function of the returned Promise
        return counter;
      }

      return null;
    })
  );

  console.log(counter);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, it looks complicate but if it works it usefull to learn. at the moment i get a error message:

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
at maybeCallback (fs.js:169:9)
at Object.readFile (fs.js:320:14)
at

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\AE925E3426D43DD22F06664D804D4525\Files\index.js:185:23
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\AE925E3426D43DD22F06664D804D4525\Files\index.js:182:7
(node:7972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process

Comment: on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 150)

Comment: Do i need to install something with npm before i can use the require libary?

Comment: @StackKanal do you have any folders in `./filesarehere`?

Comment: I have edited the code so it only reads files and not folders.  I wasn't checking for this at first because you didn't check in your code either.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the teaching, your code does work now without error message. i will use your example in the future to work better with promises, its difficult sometimes to get a good overview about this thinks.